# Django rest elasticsearch filter range in url query params

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am using elasticsearch with django rest framework. I am using this lib:
https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/

I am trying to filter by price range according to these docs: https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/

This is my views:

```
class TestAPIView(DocumentViewSet):
    document = TestDocument
    serializer_class =  TestSerializer

    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()

    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend
    ]


    filter_fields = {
        'price': {
            'field': 'price',
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
            ],
        },
    }
```

and this is my `document.py` file

```
@registry.register_document
class TestDocument(Document):
    price = fields.IntegerField(attr='price')
    class Index:
        name = 'TestModel'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = TestModel
        fields = [
            'id',
        ]
```

When I hit on browser this url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/api/v1/test-model/?price=12` It works very well, even when I try with this url : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/api/v1/test-model/?price=55` it works,

I am facing a problem to filter by range, like I want to filter price `12` to price `90`, in this case how can I pass query parameter for the range? can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/blob/0.22.4/src/django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf/constants.py#L147-L148) provides an example for this:

> ```
> # Example: {"query": {"range": {"age": {"gte": "16", "lte": "67"}}}}
> # Example: http://localhost:8000/api/users/?age__range=16__67
> ```

You thus can filter with:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/api/v1/test-model/?price__range=12__90
```

to retrieve items with a price between 12 and 90.